# cannot search and select record in sfdatagrid of syncfusion in Old Version for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion version 13.34000.0.7  in which there is no amenity of search and select. it only work on the latest version.

i want this result on my old version.

[image]

The only code in the latest version that make this possible is SearchHelper:

```
private void searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    text = (e.Source as TextBox).Text.ToLower();
    this.datagrid.SearchHelper.Search(text);
    datagrid.SearchHelper.FindNext(text);
    SetSelectedItem();
}
```

Please any one tell me how to do this on Old version. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Due to complexities, we are unable to merge the Search implementation in your 13.34000.0.7 branch. So, please upgrade to latest Syncfusion version to utilize the Search implementation.

Regards, 
Jai Ganesh S